# Get input value outside iframe

Tags: javascript, input, iframe, return-value

let's say I have this iframe

```
<iframe id="someID" class="someClass"
frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
src="some link"
style="some style here"></iframe>
```

And this example of content iframe:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body data_frameName="uniqueBodyIframe" style="zoom: 1;">
        <div class="autocompleteInput">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" class="react-autosuggest__input" value="some value">
            ... some code....
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to get value from input from this iframe.
I am trying to find all iframes on my page (because it is not only iframe). Then I need to get input value, but I don't know how to do it:

```
oWindow = window.top;
    var iframes = (oWindow).$('iframe');

    for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var iframeDoc = iframes[i].contentDocument ? iframes[i].contentDocument : iframes[i].contentWindow.document;

        if ($(iframeDoc.body).attr('data_frameName') === 'uniqueBodyIframe') {
            var inputValue = 
            
        }
    }
```

I can't change application infrastructure, so this is only one way to get the unique iframe

```
 <body data_frameName="uniqueBodyIframe" style="zoom: 1;">
```

Comment: iframe needs to be same host or you have admin access to page within iframe. Basically do you own the page within the iframe?

Comment: Yes. I am owner. And iframe is on the same host. This iframe is used to show popup window.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't have a `.class`, `#id`, or some other identifying attribute on target iframe, you can collect all of them inyo a NodeList:

```
const win = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
```

Then determine the index position of target iframe so you can use the bracket notation and index to target iframe. Use the `.contentDocument` property to hook into the document object within iframe and the `.value` property to get the input value.

```
 // This is targeting the third iframe
 let val = win[2].contentDocument.querySelector('input').value;
```

The example below will not work on SO due to security measures in sandbox. If you want to test it, you can copy and paste it to a text editor and save it with the html extension. (*.html).

```js
const getVal = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const io = e.currentTarget.elements;
  const win = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
  let val = win[2].contentDocument.querySelector('input').value;
  io.view.value = val;
};

const ui = document.forms.ui;
ui.onsubmit = getVal;
```

```html
<iframe src='example.com' height='10'></iframe>
<iframe src='example.com' height='10'></iframe>
<iframe srcdoc="<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><input value='BINGO!'></body></html>" height='50'></iframe>
<iframe src='example.com' height='10'></iframe>
<form id='ui'>
  <button>Get Value</button><br>
  <output id='view'></output>
</form>
```

Comment: It works, but not correctly. I am able to get input value. Problem is that this iframe has  more input values and selector takes first input value.  How to get all inputs and then filter inputs and get only one?

Comment: Your question asked for one input in a single iframe. Your example also has one iframe (although you mentioned there are multiple iframes) and a single input. So is my answer really incorrect or did you neglect to mention that important detail? Update the answer to explain that there are multiple inputs within the iframe and what you need exactly from the inputs. You just commented you need to filter inputs down to one? How would I know how to help you if haven't even told me what's needed to be found? Is it a specific value? An input with a specific selector? I don't read minds.